# How to create a timeout while reading from a Socket InputStream

Tags: java, sockets

I am reading some values from a solar converter. My code runs endlessly if the solar converter powers off during transmission.

```
if (ping(ip)){
    socket = new Socket(ip, port);
    fromServer = socket.getInputStream();
    toServer = socket.getOutputStream();
    try {
        System.out.println("SEND MESSAGE");
        toServer.write(message.getBytes(Charset.forName(ANSI_CODE)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();         
    }
                                      
    message = "";
    while((i=fromServer.read())!=-1){
        // converts integer to character
        if (i == 0){
        }else{
            message += (char)i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED");
}
```

If the solar converter is running, the code works great, but if the converter powers off because the sun is down, it runs in a loop. It only displays this on the console, no Exception will be thrown.

```
PING ... OK
SEND MESSAGE
```

How can I create a kind of timeout?

Answer (score 0):

To set a Timeout on any Socket, you can use `socket.setSoTimeout(MILLISECONDS)` as specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)).

This will cause any read() on the socket to only last the given milliseconds.
Note that you have to use the function before executing the blocking operation. A SocketTimeoutExeception will be thrown when the time is over.